# Receiving message from injected JavaScript in a React Native WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

In my React Native App, I'm using a WebView to display a google ad (AdSense) by using the "injectedJavascript" prop. The problem is I can't know the height of the ad in advance. So I give it a random height at first and when its style is updated, I plan to set its height correctly.

I assume I have to get the height in the injected JS code, and then use the "window.postMessage()" method to send it to the WebView through the "onMessage" prop.

MutationObserver combined with promises seem very appropriate for this case. For now, I'd like to just receive the message from the webview. So this is my code right now but no message is sent :

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

_onMessage(e) {
    console.warn(e.nativeEvent.data);
}

render() {
    const jsCode = ` 
        window._googCsa('ads', pageOptions, adblock1);

        function waitForAdSense(id) {
            var config = {
                attributes: true,
                attributeFilter: ['style'],
            };

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var adSenseElement = document.body.getElementById(id);
            if (adSenseElement.style) {
                resolve(adSenseElement.style.height);
                return;
            }
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                if (mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
                    observer.disconnect();
                    resolve(adSenseElement);
                    return;
                }
            });
        });
        observer.observe(adSenseElement, config);
    });
    }

    waitForAdSense('afscontainer1').then(height => {
    window.postMessage(height, '*');
    });
    `;
    return (
    <ScrollView>
        <WebView
        key={'AdSense'}
        ref={'webview2'}
        style={{ height: 300 }}
        source={{
            uri: isAndroid
            ? 'file:///android_asset/widget/adSense.html'
            : './widget/index.html',
        }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        mixedContentMode="compatibility"
        injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        onMessage={this._onMessage}
        scalesPageToFit
        startInLoadingState={true}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        />
        ;
    </ScrollView>
    );
}
}
```

Though, I can make it work with this code but setTimeout is not the best solution :

```
  window._googCsa('ads', pageOptions, adblock1);

  var adSenseContainer = document.getElementById("afscontainer1");

  setTimeout(function(){ window.postMessage(adSenseContainer.style.height, '*'); },1000);
```

Do you have any ideas ? I think my function waitForAdSense() might be bugged somehow. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why are using AdSense and not AdMob?

Comment: This specific ad is an iframe and needs to be implemented inside a WebView.

Comment: Then this specific ad needs to be probably implemented to mobile using mobile standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work with this changes in the injected code :

```
window._googCsa('ads', pageOptions, adblock1);

  function waitForAdSense() {
      var config = {
          attributes: true,
          attributeFilter: ["style"]
      };

      var adSenseContainer = document.getElementById("afscontainer1");

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
              mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                  if (mutation.attributeName === 'style' && adSenseContainer.style.height) {
                      var height = adSenseContainer.style.height;
                      resolve(height);
                      observer.disconnect();
                      return;
                  };
              });
          });
          observer.observe(adSenseContainer, config);
      });
  };

    waitForAdSense().then(height => {
        window.postMessage(height, '*');
    });
```

Thanks for the advices !

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use AdMob instead of AdSense on a React Native mobile application. It is somewhat pointless to mess around with these issues as the AdSense javascript wasn't made with this use case in mind. Here is a [library](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob) made to easily integrate AdMob within your app.